# Как отправить запрос на сервер с помощью библиотеки Retrofit

Tags: android, http, retrofit

Ситуация следующая, нужно используя http basic auth отправить POST на сервер. Данные которые нужно отправить должный быть json, вида

```
{
    "value1": [
        {
            "value2": "param1",
            "value3": "param2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Можно ли просто сделать этот json, toString(), и передать на сервер, или есть механизм у Retrofit для этого, и подскажите про basic auth, может я что не так делаю.

Это в Api классе.

```
 public  void getUserInfo(@Field("user") String userName, Callback<Response> cb);
```

Это для отправки json и basic auth.

```
  final String basic =
            "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://api")
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

    builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Authorization", basic);
           // request.addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json");
        }
    });

    RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();

    TestId service = restAdapter.create(TestId.class);

    service.getUserInfo(resultJsonStart.toString(), new Callback<Response>() {
        public void success(Response arg0, retrofit.client.Response arg1) {
            stringFromResponse(arg1);
            System.out.println(arg1.toString());
        }

        public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
            System.out.println(arg0.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: `может я что не так делаю` знать бы еще, что вы делаете...

Comment: Ой, извините, хотел добавить, но походу отвлекся.